# Digital signature prefix issue

Tags: xml, web-services, security

I am facing an issue and cannot figure out what i am missing.I am calculating a digital signature in c# and cannot get the right signature value.Does anybody know if signature prefix can change the signature value? My webservice wants a "ds" prefix and what i do fom code is to calculate the signature and after that add the prefix.Could this be the problem? My digest value is the right one but the signature value is different.Is it necessary to first set the prefix and after that calculate the signature?
Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to say at least what kind of crypto is involved... for example is this an RSA signature? You might also want to show your code.

Comment: It is an xmldsig#RSA-SHA1.I have a part of my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045526/signature-reference.

Comment: It is an xmldsig#RSA-SHA1.I have a part of my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045526/signature-reference.I have been progressing a little bit . I have my valid signature(tested with soap ui) that i need and the only thing that is different from what i get from my code is the signature value.That why i was wondering if those prefix namespaces somehow influence the signature value.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still have this issue, but if someone finds this thread like I did, here's the solution I found. I had quite the opposite problem, I needed to take off the "ds:" prefix, so I used setDefaultNamespacePrefix() method, from DOMSignContext class. Here's the code:

> DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Rps").item(indexNFEs));
>
> dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix(""); // this is what really matters
>
> signature.sign(dsc);

So, to insert the "ds:" you could try to use setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds:")

Hope this helps you or anyone else that might come to this page!